# Ugly, laggy focal length transitions

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I've got a problem with a sequence render (eevee), apparently caused by keyframe-controlled focal length change, which causes these really ugly step-by-step blur transitions on the whole scene:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxqmpzxzb2ftjc9/_0001288-1741.mov?dl=0
I've tried every render setting option I could think of that might affect this kind of thing, but nothing seems to affect the problem. Surely though there has to be some way to make focal length transitions actually smooth..?
Any ideas are much appreciated. Thanks!

[image: screenshot]

explanation attempt: this shot is split in half, two frames, left side is the earlier frame, right side the following one, you can see that the blurrieness makes a big leap from one frame to another.

Comment: Hello. Please use the tools dedicated to this site to share files. Also consider adding screenshots to provide better explanation of your issue. Thanks.

Comment: I've tried to add a gif, but it was too large in in order to show the actual problem, screenshots aren't of much help either, since they don't make the problem visible, but ok:

Comment: You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share the file (or equivalent test case). How are the keyframes defined?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that! Uploading the Blender file now. I just made two keyframes on the camera's focal length, starting at 934 mm going down to 50mm. That's probably very extreme and maybe the function isn't exactly made for this kind of thing (rather just for small changes I assume), but still I'm hoping to find a solution for the issue.

Comment: The upload now stopped 4 times in a row...

Comment: Usually works well but that can happen.

Comment: After over 10 tries I think it's probably pointless at the moment.

Comment: Is motion blur turned on?

Comment: Does it work in Cycles?

Comment: @Ray jaiswal no, motion blur is turned off.

Comment: @Frederik Steinmetz Did a short cycles render now, the problem doesn't seem to happen there. So it's gotta be an eevee issue.

Comment: No one's got any ideas?